# spring jpa @version auto update version before transaction uncommited

Tags: java, spring, jpa, version

below is my code. Acct Object has a field version and I used the @version annotation.

I guess because I am not committed the transaction.

it generated dirty data.

and after I query the database for same table.

jpa auto update the dirty data's version.
but besides version field. other field was not update.it make me fell confuses

saveFlush will solve the proble. but it is too slow!

```
// open transaction
            Acct acct = acctRepository.findByAcctNo("a");
            System.out.println("version1:" + acct.getVersion()); // 1
            for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i ++) {
                acct.deposit(BigDecimal.ONE);
            }
        
            System.out.println("version2:" + acct.getVersion()); // 100  
            Acct acctOther = acctRepository.findByAcctNo("b");
            
            System.out.println("version3:" + acct.getVersion()); // 2  other info is equal with version2
// commit transaction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your problem is you are probably incrementing the `acct.version` inside the `acct.deposit(BigDecimal.ONE)`. So it becomes 100
- But you are not supposed to increment `version` field yourself and hibernate will automatically increment it during flush of update operation.
- Hibernate also `auto flush` whatever so far in the session just before executing `acctRepository.findByAcctNo("b")`. When it flushes, it ignores every update you manually did to `account.version` and just auto increments it based what it has in its session. In it's session, it will remember, it gave you version 1 and so it increments it by 1 to 2 and flushes it. Just before flushing, it would have reset the incorrect version you put

Comment: yes, you are right. I increment the `acct.version` inside the `acct.deposit` method. 
besides I need save acct modify record(it contains field beforeVersion and afterVersion) in `acct.deposit` method. 
if I not modify version manual, the modify record's field beforeVersion,afterVersion always unchange . could you give some adivce.

Comment: Sorry your wuestion is closed. Cany you edit the question by addiing the Acct entity class and the issue you have?